# How to customize Unauthorized response in Quarkus?

Tags: kotlin, quarkus, unauthorized, quarkus-reactive

Because we use a custom format of error we want to customize all error responses ... in particular Forbidden (we succeed) and Unauthorized (we failed).

I read many docs, posts and I tried different solutions you can find in [my sample project](https://github.com/patrice-conil/quarkus-unauthorized-mapper/tree/main)

First: ServerExceptionMapper

```kotlin
@ServerExceptionMapper
@Priority(1)
fun unauthorized(e: UnauthorizedException) =
   mapExceptionIntoError(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED, "UNAUTHORIZED", e.message)
```

Second: ExceptionMapper

```kotlin
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHORIZATION)
class UnauthorizedErrorMapper : ExceptionMapper<UnauthorizedException> {

    private val logger: Logger = Logger.getLogger(this.javaClass.simpleName)

    @Override
    override fun toResponse(exception: UnauthorizedException): Response {
        logger.severe(exception.message)

        val message = exception.message
        val code = STATUS.statusCode
        val error =  ErrorInfo(STATUS.statusCode, STATUS.name, message)

        return Response
            .status(code)
            .entity(error)
            .build()
    }

    companion object {
        private val STATUS = Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED
    }
}
```

Third: failureHandler

```kotlin
@ApplicationScoped
class UnauthorizedExceptionHandler {
    fun init(@Observes router: Router) {
        router.route().failureHandler { event ->
            if (event.failure() is UnauthorizedException) {
                event.response().end("CUSTOMIZED_RESPONSE")
            } else {
                event.next()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With no success.
What did I miss or do wrong?

Thanks in advance
Patrice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ServerExceptionMapper works only for /hello using RolesAllowed annotation like in

```kotlin
    @GET
    @Path("/hello")
    @RolesAllowed("role1")
    fun hello(): RestResponse<Reply> = RestResponse.ok(Reply("Hello from RESTEasy Reactive"))


    @GET
    @Path("/helloNotAnnotated")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    fun helloNotAnnotated() = RestResponse.ok(Reply("Hello from helloNotAnnotated"))
```

and not for role2 defined in application.properties using elytron

```
quarkus.security.users.embedded.enabled=true
quarkus.security.users.embedded.plain-text=true
quarkus.security.users.embedded.users.user=password
quarkus.security.users.embedded.roles.role1=user
quarkus.security.users.embedded.roles.role2=user
quarkus.http.auth.permission.role-role2.paths=/helloNotAnnotated
quarkus.http.auth.permission.role-role2.policy=role2-policy
quarkus.http.auth.policy.role2-policy.roles-allowed=role2
```

See differences in action in [my sample project](https://github.com/patrice-conil/quarkus-unauthorized-mapper/tree/main)

Answer (score 1):

This use case does work as we have a [test](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/3.3.1/extensions/resteasy-reactive/quarkus-resteasy-reactive/deployment/src/test/java/io/quarkus/resteasy/reactive/server/test/security/CustomExceptionMapperTest.java) in the repo that does this.

```
public static final class CustomExceptionMappers {

    @ServerExceptionMapper(UnauthorizedException.class)
    public Response forbidden() {
        return Response.status(999).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes as I said it works with forbidden ... but not for Unauthorized. :(

Comment: Maybe a kotlin side effect. @geoand have you tried to run tests in my repo ?

Comment: I have not unfortunately

Comment: Hi @geoand, 
I investigate more and found that we haven't same behaviour using RolesAllowed on resource path or by defining roles in application.properties
When I define role via annotation, as you do in the test, everything works like a charm but when role is defined in application.properties CustomExceptionMapper is never called.